# скопировать .png файлы с одной директории в другую

Tags: perl

```
readdir (DIR, "../doc/application_notes/alint_pro_getting_started/") or die "Can't open directory with images$!";#opendir
    foreach('*.png')
    {
        copy('*png','../release/strb/*.pmg') or die "Can't copy images for html$!"; #copy img;
    }
    closedir DIR;
```

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, нажав [edit]

Comment: Из формулировки вопроса не совсем понятно, в чём же проблема. Ошибка какая-то?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use File::Copy;
use strict;

my $src = "1"; # каталог-источник "./1"
my $dst = "2"; # каталог-приемник "./2"
opendir(my $dh, $src) || die "Can't opendir $src: $!";
my @file = grep { /.+\.png$/ && -f "$src/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;
map { copy("$src/$_","$dst/$_") or die "Copy failed: $!"; } @file;
```

Comment: `/.+\.png$/` :)

Comment: Есть такое дело :) Поправил.